# Prevent C++Builder from adding Process information to debug string output?

Tags: c++builder

I am outputting debug information `OutputDebugString()` in C++Builder 11.3, however it keeps adding `Process xxx.exe (####)` and extra line feeds.  It makes it hard to read what is going on, is there a way to turn that off?

TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Embarcadero's documentation:

[Event Log Options](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Event_Log_Options)

> **Tools > Options > Debugger > Event Log**
>
> Use this dialog box to control the content, size, and appearance of the event log.
>
> General
>
> | Item | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | Display process info with event | Shows the process name and process ID for the process that generated each event. |